# Html and Css Hover Functions

Tags: html, css, text, hover

Hi I am new to html and css and I would like to display a text on the right side when I hover the mouse over another text which is on the left side. I have a list of texts displayed on the left side here is the cod for it

```
<ul>
    <li id="what">What Is Eco Flash?</li>
    <br>
    <li id="water">We Coneserve Water!</li>
    <br>
    <li id="chemicals">Chemicals Reduction!</a>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li id="waste">No Waste-Water Run Off</li>
</ul>
```

and this is my css code for the list to be displayed on the left side

```
width:25%;
text-align: left;
font-family: 'Copperplate Gothic Light';
font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: small-caps;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
margin:.2em;
display: list-item;
```

now that I want to add is a small explanation text for each item in the list to appear on the right side when I hover over them.

I am new to the html and css and I have tried spam but it appears right under the text. How can I get the explanation text to appear on the right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `:hover` on the parent and then display the child node like this:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4Lyr61k/)

```css
ul li .description{
  display: none;
}
ul li:hover .description{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="what">What Is Eco Flash? <span class="description">Boom a description</span></li>
  <li id="water">We Coneserve Water! <span class="description">Boom a description again</span></li>
  <li id="chemicals">Chemicals Reduction!</li>
  <li id="waste">No Waste-Water Run Off</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add extra markup to your list elements, you could use a `data-` attribute and the `:after` pseudo-class in CSS. I realize this may be a bit more advanced that what you're looking for, but it might be good for future visitors:

```css
li:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-explanation);
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="what" data-explanation="My explanation">What Is Eco Flash?</li>
    <li id="water">We Coneserve Water!</li>
    <li id="chemicals">Chemicals Reduction!</li>
    <li id="waste">No Waste-Water Run Off</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new element to the `li`:

```
<li id="water">
   We Coneserve Water!
   <small>Explanation...</small>
</li>
```

Which is hidden by default:

```
li small{
   display:none;
}
```

Then display it when the `li` is hovered over:

```
li:hover small{
   display:inline;
}
```